# Let $R_1$ and $R_2$ be reflexive relations on a set $S$. Prove that $R_1\cup R_2$ and $R_1 \cap R_2$ are reflexive.

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

How do I go about proving this?

Comment: Do you know what a reflexive relation is?

Comment: All I have is that (s,s)∈R1 for every element s∈R1 and (s,s)∈R2 for every element s∈R2. @MayankDeora

Comment: Okay. Pick an element  $s\in S$. Do you know that $(s,s)\in R_1\cup R_2$?

Comment: No, I have to prove that too.

Comment: If you know that $(s,s) \in R_1$ and $(s,s) \in R_2$ (which are assumptions that you're given), do you know that $(s,s)\in R_1 \cup R_2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, to prove a relation $R$ is reflexive on a set $S$, we need to prove $(s, s) \in R$ for all $s \in S$. Since we already know this is true for $R_1$ and $R_2$, it becomes very easy to prove this for their intersection and union.

---

Given an element $s \in S$, we know that $(s, s) \in R_1$ and $(s, s) \in R_2$ because $R_1, R_2$ are reflexive.

Since $(s, s)$ is in both sets, it is also in the intersection of the sets, so $(s, s) \in R_1 \cap R_2$. Therefore, $R_1 \cap R_2$ is reflexive.

Since $(s, s) \in R_1$ and $R_1 \subseteq (R_1 \cup R_2)$, we can deduce that $(s, s) \in R_1 \cup R_2$. Therefore, $R_1 \cup R_1$ is reflexive.

Comment: How is (R1∪R2) a subset of R1. Wouldn't the union of R1 and R2 have more elements than R1?

Comment: @Hector Sorry, you're right, it should be $R_1 \subseteq (R_1 \cup R_2)$. I've fixed it in my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

For first part as Noble Mushtak said $R_1 \cap R_2$ is reflexive.
Now for second part $R_1 \cup R_2=R_1 or R_2 - (R_1 \cap R_2)$ i.e. that part of $R_1$ and $R_2$ which are only one time in $R_1 \cap R_2$ which are also reflexive as we have seen . That's it